# Operator Norm of Convoultion with Indicator Function

Tags: operator-theory, convolution

If we consider $T$ as the convolution of $f \in L^2$ with the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$, e.g. $Tf:=f * \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}$. I want to calculate the Operator Norm of $T$, $||T||$.

Using Young, i get $||f * \mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}||_p \leq ||f|| ||\mathbb{1}_{[0,1]}||_1 = ||f||_p$, thus $||T|| = \sup_{||f||=1} ||Tf|| \leq \sup_{||f||=1} ||f||_p = 1$.

I also think that $||T|| = 1$, but don't know how to show that $||T|| \geq 1$.

Comment: Tip: Consider the indicator functions $f_n := 1_{[-n, n ]}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and remember that $\Vert T \Vert \geq \frac{\Vert T f_n \Vert}{\Vert f_n\Vert}$

Comment: Thanks for the hint @G.Chiusole, so as $\lVert f_n \rVert = 1$ (using the Uniform norm) i just have to look at $\lVert Tfn \rVert$ which is $\geq 1$, as $Tf_n(x)=\int_0^1 f_n(x-y)dy=\int_{-n}^{n+1}dy \geq 1$.